# How to add text views and buttons on Google Maps fragment?

Tags: android, android-studio, google-maps, maps

[image: This is the sort of view I want]This is a simple layout and I wanted to add text views and 5 buttons on it but whatever I do those buttons don't appear on the map.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <!--fragment to display our maps-->


    <!--Search View for the google autocomplete support -->
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MapsActivity" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: not using relativelayout. Use constraintlayout or framelayout

Answer (score 1):

Your xml should look something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:layoutDirection="ltr">

<androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
    android:id="@+id/map_layout"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn"
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="25dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

you can add more buttons/TextView